# Unknown cause for key error while parsing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following function below which goes to each of the values of the values of the dictionary `tickerdata` and then updates them once certain parameters are met. The function iterates over the values correctly, however there are multiple key errors the origin of which I am not sure of. I am sure that I have defined `tickerdata` with all the names from `tickers`. Below are my functions.

```
def fetchstock(stock):
        endpoint = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{stock_ticker}/quotes?'
        full_url = endpoint.format(stock_ticker=stock)
        page = requests.get(url=full_url, params= {'apikey':td_consumer_key})
        content = json.loads(page.content)
        return content[stock]

def scandata(volumelimita, volumelimitb, lastchangelimita,lastchangelimitb, ivlimita, ivlimitb):
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    tickerdata = {key: {} for key in tickers}
    keydefine = {"price":0, "volume":0, "netchange":0, "iv":0}
    tickerdata = {key: keydefine.copy() for key in tickers}
    scandict = {}
    for i in range(100):
        #print("increment is "+str(i))
        stock = tickers[i]
        try:
            if((fetchstock(stock)['totalVolume']>volumelimita) and (fetchstock(stock)['totalVolume']< volumelimitb) and (fetchstock(stock)['netChange']>lastchangelimita) and (fetchstock(stock)['netChange']< lastchangelimitb) and((fetchstock(stock)['volatility']*100)>ivlimita)and((fetchstock(stock)['volatility']*100)<ivlimitb)):
                tickerdata[stock]['price'] = fetchstock(stock)['lastPrice']
                tickerdata[stock]['volume'] = fetchstock(stock)['totalVolume']
                tickerdata[stock]['netchange']= fetchstock(stock)['netChange']
                tickerdata[stock]['iv'] = fetchstock(stock)['volatility']*100
                scandict[stock ] = {"price":tickerdata[stock]['price'], "volume":tickerdata[stock]['volume'],
                                    "netchange":tickerdata[stock]['netchange'], "iv":tickerdata[stock]['iv']}
        except KeyError:
            print('here was a key error at '+ stock)
            pass
    return scandict       

print(scandata(0,10000000,-0.99,0.99,0,25))
```

output:

```
here was a key error at ALK
here was a key error at ALB
here was a key error at ARE
here was a key error at ALXN
here was a key error at ALGN
here was a key error at ALLE
here was a key error at LNT
here was a key error at ALL
here was a key error at GOOGL
here was a key error at GOOG
here was a key error at MO
here was a key error at AMZN
here was a key error at AMCR
here was a key error at AEE
here was a key error at AAL
here was a key error at AEP
here was a key error at AXP
here was a key error at AIG
here was a key error at AMT
here was a key error at AWK
here was a key error at AMP
here was a key error at ABC
here was a key error at AME
here was a key error at AMGN
here was a key error at APH
here was a key error at ADI
here was a key error at ADM
here was a key error at AIZ
here was a key error at ADSK
here was a key error at ADP
here was a key error at AZO
here was a key error at AVB
here was a key error at AVY
here was a key error at BKR
here was a key error at BLL
here was a key error at BAC
here was a key error at BK
here was a key error at BAX
here was a key error at BDX
here was a key error at BRK.B
here was a key error at BBY
here was a key error at BIO
here was a key error at BIIB
here was a key error at BLK
here was a key error at BA
here was a key error at BKNG
here was a key error at BWA
here was a key error at BXP
here was a key error at BSX
here was a key error at BMY
here was a key error at AVGO
here was a key error at BR
here was a key error at BF.B
here was a key error at CHRW
here was a key error at COG
here was a key error at CDNS
here was a key error at CPB
here was a key error at COF
here was a key error at CAH
here was a key error at KMX
here was a key error at CCL
here was a key error at CARR
here was a key error at CTLT
here was a key error at CAT
here was a key error at CBOE
here was a key error at CBRE
here was a key error at CDW
here was a key error at CE
here was a key error at CNC
here was a key error at CNP
here was a key error at CERN
here was a key error at CF
here was a key error at SCHW
{'MMM': {'price': 173.52, 'volume': 1875764, 'netchange': -0.5, 'iv': 3.9899999999999998}, 'ABT': {'price': 106.8, 'volume': 4718995, 'netchange': -0.22, 'iv': 1.92}, 'ATVI': {'price': 83.68, 'volume': 5864152, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 2.93}, 'ADBE': {'price': 475.0, 'volume': 3561554, 'netchange': -0.91, 'iv': 3.1300000000000003}, 'AAP': {'price': 157.0, 'volume': 906915, 'netchange': -0.66, 'iv': 3.29}, 'AES': {'price': 20.94, 'volume': 4495472, 'netchange': -0.21, 'iv': 2.07}, 'AFL': {'price': 45.5, 'volume': 3314639, 'netchange': 0.66, 'iv': 1.77}, 'A': {'price': 118.48, 'volume': 1400768, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.39}, 'APD': {'price': 267.36, 'volume': 751837, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.46}, 'AKAM': {'price': 103.53, 'volume': 1110303, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.34}, 'ANSS': {'price': 335.185, 'volume': 329790, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 5.86}, 'ANTM': {'price': 311.4, 'volume': 1372850, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.5000000000000004}, 'AON': {'price': 204.11, 'volume': 1453281, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.19}, 'AOS': {'price': 56.36, 'volume': 717023, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.01}, 'APA': {'price': 16.02, 'volume': 8903476, 'netchange': -0.08, 'iv': 3.95}, 'AMAT': {'price': 88.08, 'volume': 5776367, 'netchange': -0.22, 'iv': 2.25}, 'APTV': {'price': 122.24, 'volume': 1599289, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 3.44}, 'ANET': {'price': 277.34, 'volume': 610471, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 6.36}, 'AJG': {'price': 119.94, 'volume': 995751, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 2.4}, 'ATO': {'price': 99.07, 'volume': 1100930, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 2.0500000000000003}}
```

Not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: A good start would be to actually _print_ the exception, so you at least know exactly where the error is.  As it is, there are like twelve different spots where the error could be.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've run it a couple of times without the try and except handler. The key errors seems to be for random names. For example, I got `<ipython-input-73-7c5b26408228> in fetchstock(stock)
      4         page = requests.get(url=full_url, params= {'apikey':td_consumer_key})
      5         content = json.loads(page.content)
----> 6         return content[stock]
      7 
      8 def scandata(volumelimita, volumelimitb, lastchangelimita,lastchangelimitb, ivlimita, ivlimitb):

KeyError: 'AAL'`

Comment: It's hard to read formatted code in comments.  Better to update the question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code and modified:

`tickers = save_sp500_tickers()` to `tickers = ['LNT', 'AVGO', 'MMM', 'BAC']`

The result:

```
{'LNT': {'price': 51.705, 'volume': 810208, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 2.53}, 'AVGO': {'price': 405.0, 'volume': 2666510, 'netchange': -0.82, 'iv': 4.9}, 'MMM': {'price': 173.52, 'volume': 1875764, 'netchange': -0.5, 'iv': 3.9899999999999998}}
```

LNT, AVGO and BAC were the tickers that your program had key errors for, I threw in MMM to make sure your accepted values would work as well.

Most likely, the problem is that API's usually have a limit on how often you can request, and you are calling `fetchstock(stock)` too often in your `for` loop. You should instead call it only once per ticker, assign it to a variable and then check it's `['lastPrice'] ['totalVolume']` etc...

Also, your super larger `if` statement doesn't need most of those parentheses (if it's all on one line you don't need any), and the expression can be simplified (PyCharm did it for me after removing all the parentheses)

**Final Code:**

```
def scandata(volumelimita, volumelimitb, lastchangelimita, lastchangelimitb, ivlimita, ivlimitb):
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    tickerdata = {key: {} for key in tickers}
    keydefine = {"price": 0, "volume": 0, "netchange": 0, "iv": 0}
    tickerdata = {key: keydefine.copy() for key in tickers}
    scandict = {}
    for i in range(100):
        # print("increment is "+str(i))
        stock = tickers[i]
        try:

            # Check if close to rate limit, if true then wait 1 minute
            if i % 100:
                time.sleep(60)

            # Call function once per loop and assign to variable
            current_stock = fetchstock(stock)

            if (volumelimita < current_stock['totalVolume'] < volumelimitb and
                    lastchangelimita < current_stock['netChange'] < lastchangelimitb and
                    ivlimita < current_stock['volatility'] * 100 < ivlimitb):

                tickerdata[stock]['price'] = current_stock['lastPrice']
                tickerdata[stock]['volume'] = current_stock['totalVolume']
                tickerdata[stock]['netchange'] = current_stock['netChange']
                tickerdata[stock]['iv'] = current_stock['volatility'] * 100

                scandict[stock] = {"price": tickerdata[stock]['price'],
                                   "volume": tickerdata[stock]['volume'],
                                   "netchange": tickerdata[stock]['netchange'],
                                   "iv": tickerdata[stock]['iv']}
        except KeyError:
            print('here was a key error at ' + stock)
            pass
    return scandict


print(scandata(0, 10000000, -0.99, 0.99, 0, 25))
```

**PRE Edit**

If you're still getting issues, try putting a `time.sleep(10)` at the end of your `for` loop. TD Ameritrade API has a limit request of 120 requests per minute so if you have more than 120 tickers to go through and the program is fast enough to send them all in one minute, your requests will get blocked again.

**POST Edit**

Explained in comments, if you only request once per stock symbol you don't really need `time.sleep()` unless you are checking more than 120 stocks within one minute. I added a statement `if i % 100: time.sleep(60)` which makes it so the program waits 1 minute every 100 symbols which will help not trigger the request limit.

One final closing thought, you could import the `traceback` module and get more info on the exception, here's an example:

```
import traceback

try:
    print(2/0)
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I had forgotten about rate limiting for more than 120 requests. I will try `time.sleep(10)` to fix it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! While adding `time.sleep(10)` would fix the rate limit, I'd still recommend calling `fetchstock()` only once per loop as it would be more efficient. If you have 100 stocks to go through, using `time.sleep(10)` would take 16 minutes to go through all of them (100 x 10 / 60) and (in your original code) you call `fetchstock()` 10 times per symbol, so for 100 stocks that's 1000 requests. It could all be done under a minute if you only call `fetchstock()` once per stock with 100 stocks, that would only be 100 queries and under the request limit.

Comment: The `time.sleep()` fix should only be used if you have more than 100 stocks to go through, and in that case I would do add this: `if i % 100: time.sleep(60)` at the start of your `for` loop which would check if `i` is divisible by 100, (meaning you're close to your rate limit) then you wait a minute before continuing. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I see. I have put time(10) at the end of the for loop and tried with tickers, takes a while but it seems to get the job done